# WS2812B LED Stripe going crazy with Arduino and External Power Supply

Tags: power, ws2812

I have a simple connection here:

- A WS2812B 5m 300 leds strip 5V;
- A Power Supply MS-150-5 150W 5V;
- Arduino with a simple code to blink 10 first leds;

TEST:
If I connect my power supply to my LED with a wireless controller with some saved presets, everything works fine. Colors, red, blue, white ( some voltage downhere ), but ok, working.
If take off the wireless controller and connect the LED to the Arduino, GND,+5, DATA, with a simple code, it's ok, 10 leds blinking, working fine. 
BUT if I connect only the data to Arduino and connect the power to my power supply, now all the stripe go crazy, show no sense colors.

The Arduino code is ok, voltage is ok. Power supply is big enough. Even say to blink only one light is turning on all leds.

I was with a differente power supply before, same but 70w and was working ok. Now with 150w is not working. Why is not working with this one that is bigger? Maybe any noise ?

I'm connecting the power supply directly to the LED and only using the Arduino Data.

Comment: So... you [don't connect the grounds together?](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/importance-sharing-grounds)

Comment: The Arduino GND and the power supply? No.

Comment: Well there is your problem, they need a common ground forthe signal to get through correctly.

Comment: Tks guys. I'm using the USB power for the Arduino and the external power supply for the LED. I'll try to use all the same source power and post here the result.

Comment: the source need not be the same, and usually isn't, the ground (aka common) needs to be, well, common.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the Gnd from the Arduino and power supply are connected together - otherwise it would cause a common issue. Another recommendation would be to include a capacitor, usually a size of 1000uf is recommended.

Comment: Tks! Now is working like a charme. Was the GND between Arduino and the Strip.

Answer (score 0):

Tks for reply guys. Thats correct. I have connected the GND of the external power supply with the GNC of Arduino and everything is fine.